# Java generics with unbounded wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, wildcard

I have an interface to convert object to string:

```
public interface Converter<T> {
    String asString(T object);
}
```

And a map to store all available converters:

```
Map<Class<?>, Converter<?>> converterMap;
```

Now I have a list of heterogeneous data to convert like this:

```
List<?> data = fetchData();
List<String> stringData = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
for (Object datum : data) {
    stringData.add(convertrMap.get(datum.getClass()).asString(datum));
}
```

But this code doesn't compile:

```
error: method asString in interface Converter<T> cannot be applied to given types;
            stringData.add(converterMap.get(datum.getClass()).asString(datum));
  required: CAP#1
  found: Object
  reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Converter
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

How should I change the code?

Comment: Why don't you use `asString(Object object)` instead of using `Converter<T>` and then using `Converter<?>` it makes use of generics redundant.

Comment: This works but the type information is lost, making the `asString` method unsafe, e.g. I can safely use `Converter<Date> dateConverter = (Converter<Date>) converterMap.get(Date.class)`.

Comment: I can't see how it makes it unsafe. Even your current design is unsafe if you map the converter object & class wrongly . Statement like `Converter<?> c = new Converter<String>; c.asString("abc");` is illegal because `?` is unknown at the runtime therefore it only expect some subtype of this unknown type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing issue called [wildcard capture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).
Java is unable to identify the type that will be received from the `List<?>` data. 
Try refactoring your code in any of the two ways

**Method 1:** Change your interface as below

```
interface Converter {
    String asString(Object object);
}
```

**Method 2:** Helper method to capture wild card by type inference

Create an helper method as below,

```
// Helper method created so that the wildcard can be captured
// through type inference.
private <T> void helper(List<T> data) {
    Map<Class<?>, Converter<T>> converterMap = null;
    List<String> stringData = null;

    for (T datum : data) {
        stringData.add(converterMap.get(datum.getClass()).asString(datum));
    }
}
```

Call this helper method as below

```
List<?> data = fetchData();
helper(data);
```

Comment: I think it's unsafe to change the parameter type to `Object`, e.g. I can invoke `asString("")` on a integer converter. I also have some other code that needs this type information.

Comment: what's the point of the `T` in `Converter` if you are not using it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should encapsulate the map inside a helper class like this, whose operations preserve the invariant (that `Class<T>` maps to `Converter<T>`):

```
public class ConverterMap {
    Map<Class<?>, Converter<?>> converterMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Converter<?>>();
    public <T> void addConverter(Class<T> clazz, Converter<T> converter) {
        converterMap.put(clazz, converter);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Converter<T> getConverter(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (Converter<T>)converterMap.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

Now, to break down the task, let's take the small step of writing a function that takes any object and converts it based on the converter map (assuming the object's class is in the converter map):

```
ConverterMap cm = new ConverterMap;
private static String convert(Object x);
```

This seems simple, but is harder than it looks, because you will run into a special case of the Java type system in how it types `.getClass()`. You will have the problem of convincing the compiler that `x` is an instance of the parameter of `x.getClass()`. The best way to solve this is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> String convert2(Class<T> clazz, Object x) {
    return cm.getConverter(clazz).asString((T)x);
    // you can alternately do clazz.cast(x) instead of the unchecked cast (T)x
}
private static String convert(Object x) {
    return convert2(x.getClass(), x);
}
```

And then you can solve the rest of the problem:

```
for (Object datum : data) {
    stringData.add(convert(datum));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code like this:

```
public interface Converter {
    String asString(Object object);
}
```

I think it will work.